# Compress and provide single-file access to 10 million files

Tags: tar, archiving, gzip

I have ~10 million small text files and I would like to solve the following tasks:

- compress all the data;
- put it all into 1 file to transfer over the Internet;
- be able to access each single file given the path really quickly;
- **(update)** single files to be easily accessible from within Python ecosystem.

I came up with the following solution:

- gzip each file (compression);
- add all gzipped files to a single tarball:

  single.tar
    -> /1/100/1001451.gz
    ...
    -> /9/956/9562548.gz

Does it solve my tasks?

Comment: If your actual question is "does my idea solve my task", it seems like you're in the best position to answer that.  Just try it and see, then you tell us.  If your question is something else, please be explicit in the question.  Just tossing this out there for commentary is too open ended for the site.

Answer (score 4):

I think there might be a better way to solve this: `tar`, `zip`, `rar` etc. all share the property (to a diferent degree), that access to a single file is

- not very fast
- not transparent: You can't directly view it, but need to uncompress it elsewhere, then view it

There is one alternative though: Use a compressed image file with a file system (e.g. `cloop` and ext4) or an plain image file with a compressed file system (e.g. `squashfs`) - I usually use the latter.

This way you can move your file over the Internet, and on the target system directly mount it and have speedy and transparent access to the files in it.

**EDIT**

Concerning the need to update files: I had the same problem and solved it using `mksquashfs` and `overlayfs`. Changed files go into the overlay, the originals stay in the unchanged transport file (I consider this as an important feature)

Comment: I would argue that filesystems and archive formats work almost the same way here, and share the same general properties, varying only in how efficient a path lookup is. (Very efficient in formats like ext4, acceptable in formats like Zip which have a central linear index, poor in Tar which has no index whatsoever.) Especially when it gets to write-once formats like squashfs, it seems that they only differ in random access _within_ a file (Zip requires decompressing the whole file, squashfs allows decompressing individual blocks), but are nearly the same when extracting a whole file at once.

Comment: squashfs is always faster, because it's in kernelspace, while zip is in the userspace; and you have to call the unzip binary itself on every access, what is a lot of overhead than a simple open function.

Comment: @IporSircer: Kernelspace doesn't automatically make things faster. It runs on the exact same CPU at the exact same speed. What makes things faster is well-designed format/structure (squashfs is indeed much more optimized), caching the metadata, and – as you noted – avoiding the need to start a new process and re-read the archive every time... but that's under the assumption that spawning `unzip` is the only other option. It's not: many programming languages have built-in Zip format support (less often Rar and 7z).

Comment: Nice solution, but not very friendly to the non-technical audience familiar only with Python. Updated the question though.

Comment: @grawity: You've forgotten many compiled-in security features by gcc, e.g. stack protector, pie; plus nowadays spectre/meltdown workarounds which only slow down the userspace programs. So the exactly same algo is still faster in kernelspace in reality.

Comment: @DenisKulagin: mount the squashfs to a folder, and the unexperienced user doesn't notice any difference than directly opening a local file.

Comment: @DenisKulagin The beauty of a filesystem as an abstraction layer is once you mount one, its files are available to *any* ecosystem/program/whatever that can deal with files. Very Unix-y approach.

Comment: @IporSircer: My distro's kernel appears to be compiled with STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG as well. Meltdown workarounds slow down kernel↔user context switches, and both entirely-kernelspace and entirely-userspace code remains equally unaffected. Spectre mitigations are _mostly_ applied to kernel code.

Comment: Just to reiterate: The speed of access to a single file depends on the format used - `tar`is very slow, others are much faster. None is as fast as a file system. But this is the lesser point: What I consider more important is the transparency: Mount the FS, and every tool you need can access it directly without even noticing, that it comes from a transport file.

Comment: Concerning user-friendlyness: `mksquashfs` is no more complicated than `tar`, if your users can't handle it, you might just wrap it into a shell script and fully automate the process.

Comment: Concerning user-friendlyness: that's not saying much, given that `tar` is frequently the butt of many "arcane unix tools" jokes. I agree with the general idea of being able to mount the archive as a filesystem ([see also](https://github.com/tmbdev/archivefs)), but it doesn't seem that OP has actually mentioned Linux as the target OS...

Comment: @grawity Since the OP's first idea was `tar`, it seemed logical to think in Linux terms. And `unsquashfs` for Windows works quite well.